# Hide delete button when tap back button in EKEventViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have using `EkEventViewController` to view event in my app.

My code should be like below:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let eventViewController = EkEventViewController()
       eventViewController.delegate = self
       eventViewController.allowsEditing = true
       eventViewController.allowsCalendarPreview = true
       eventViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
       eventViewController.event = self.events[indexPath.row]
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

When I tap back button from `EkEventViewController`. The delete button bar should not hide. How to hide or remove delete bottom button bar

Comment: Is the delete button bar a custom UI you made? or the bottom bar of the navigation controller?

Comment: @BenOng The bottom bar of navigation controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, I presume that the 'delete' button or border retains after tapping on back button from `EKEventViewController`. The delete button from `EKEventViewController` is actually from `toolbar` in `navigationController`. You can hide the toolbar via `setToolbarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)`

To do so, you have to initialize a new class with the subclass of `EKEventViewController` and push your view controller to it. Then, add the line below in your `viewWillDisappear` of the new class:

```
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Do note that this solution is based on assumption that you do not have existing toolbar prior to calling the `EKEventViewController`.